# Hosted Ext js 4 - Where can i find it and make my pages fetch from there?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

I have checked **[Google Hosted EXT Js](http://code.google.com/p/extjs-public/)**  and i cannot find EXT JS 4. I would want my web pages to reference the EXT JS 4 from there and not from my local Web server. Any one please get me the full path to the EXT JS 4 hosted some where on the web which is always available and can be used by another web page as in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LINK_TO_EXTJS4/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="LINK_TO_EXTJS4/ext-all.js"></script>
```

So i need those two lines above, replacing `LINK_TO_EXTJS4` directing to some EXT JS4 some where on the web so as my users browsers fetch the JavaScript library from those ends and not from my local web server. Thanks

Comment: There is also https://cdnjs.com/libraries/extjs/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's right [here](http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.0.7-gpl/ext-all.js).

You can use this script tag...

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.0.7-gpl/ext-all.js"></script>
```

EDIT:

The css tag..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.0.7-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css">
```

Comment: +1 Nice, but am still missing the `/resources/css/ext-all.css` file. Point me to that too. I need to accept your answer, if you put the link to the css file as well. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can [read here about](http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com/2008/05/speed-up-access-to-your-favorite.html) CDN/Google Load library delivery and how to get the latest version, and [here to see which libraries they currently support](http://code.google.com/intl/no-NO/apis/libraries/devguide.html#AjaxLibraries).

EXT js library 3(+) is supported, you can try using 4 and see if it delivers. If not then maybe Google hasn't  been 'allowed' to host the library yet.

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
// Load jQuery
google.load("ext-core", "4"); //this here!!!!

// on page load complete, fire off a jQuery json-p query
// against Google web search
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
$.getJSON("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?q=google&;v=1.0&;callback=?",

// on search completion, process the results
function (data) {
if (data.responseDate.results &&
data.responseDate.results.length>0) {
renderResults(data.responseDate.results);
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks but, only Ext Js 3.x is found there. I need Ext Js 4